# how to block a user in facebook via api(coding)

Tags: c#, facebook

I am developing a windows app using c#.net.
I want to block a user in facebook using api.
Any one suggest me is there any methods to block a user in facebook via api

Answer (score 1):

There is a function to ban users from your app in the Facebook REST api here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.banUsers/

The REST API is deprecated but you can call many of the same functions through the Open Graph API.

Comment: Banning a user from your application is not the same as Blocking a user (such that the logged in user cannot see the blocked user).